# Problems when fetching data from inherited classes on hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, hql

In my project I have the following superclass and its inheritants:
`public class Pessoa`
`public class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa`
`public class Cliente extends PessoaJuridica`
and I'm using Table per Subclass as inheritance method in Hibernate.
All the insertions are done correctly, but when i try to query the Pessoa class passin an Id as a parameter, it returns data from the last class of the inheritance tree only.

So, when I call

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("from Pessoa where id = :id");
qry.setParameter("id", 17);
System.out.println( qry.list() );
```

It prints only the record of the registry with id = 17 from the Cliente's class...

Am I doing something wrong with the code? Below are the sources of the project.
**Database Script**

```
CREATE TABLE public.endereco
(
_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('endereco__id_seq'::regclass),
tipo character(1),
endereco character varying(255),
numero bigint,
complemento character varying(100),
bairro character varying(100),
cidade character varying(100),
uf character varying(2),
cep character varying(9),
status character(1),
CONSTRAINT endereco_pkey PRIMARY KEY (_id),
CONSTRAINT endereco_status_check CHECK (status = ANY (ARRAY['A'::bpchar, 'I'::bpchar])),  
CONSTRAINT endereco_tipo_check CHECK (tipo = ANY (ARRAY['P'::bpchar, 'C'::bpchar, 'E'::bpchar]))
)

CREATE TABLE public.pessoa
(
_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pessoa__id_seq'::regclass),
id_endereco integer,
nome character varying(255),
status character(1),
CONSTRAINT pessoa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_pessoa_endereco FOREIGN KEY (id_endereco)
  REFERENCES public.endereco (_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT pessoa_status_check CHECK (status = ANY (ARRAY['A'::bpchar, 'I'::bpchar]))
)
    CREATE TABLE public.pessoa_juridica
(
  id_pessoa integer NOT NULL,
  cnpj character varying(20),
  insc_est character varying(20),
  razao_social character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pessoa_juridica_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_pessoa),
  CONSTRAINT fk_pj_pessoa FOREIGN KEY (id_pessoa)
      REFERENCES public.pessoa (_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE TABLE public.cliente
(
  id_pessoa integer NOT NULL,
  telefone character varying(15),
  CONSTRAINT fk_cli_pjuridica FOREIGN KEY (id_pessoa)
      REFERENCES public.pessoa (_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

**Classes**

```
public class Endereco {
    private int _id;
    private char tipo;
    private String endereco;
    private long numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;
    private String uf;
    private String cep;
    private char status;
    private Set<Pessoa> pessoas;
//Getters + Setters
}
public class Pessoa {
    private int _id;
    private Endereco endereco;
    private String nome;
    private char status;
}
public class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa {
    private String razaoSocial;
    private String cnpj;
    private String inscricaoEstadual;
}
public class Cliente extends PessoaJuridica{
    private String telefone; 
}
```

**Test Class**

```
public class TestaSelectCliente {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query qry = session.createQuery("from Pessoa");
        System.out.println(qry.list());

        Query qry1 = session.createQuery("from Pessoa where id= :id");
        qry1.setParameter("id", 17);
        System.out.println(qry1.list());
    }
}
```

> **qry Output:** [Cliente(telefone=(46)3225 - 6234), PessoaJuridica(razaoSocial=FRANCISCO S/A, cnpj=087.971.169-80, inscricaoEstadual=4.863.828), PessoaFisica(cpf=087.971.169-80, rg=4.863.828, dataNascimento=2016-01-27)]
>   All Records from all tables<
>
> **qry1 Output:** [Cliente(telefone=(46)3225 - 6234)]
>   Data from the last Class on the hierarchy table.<

What am I doing wrong / forgetting to do?

Comment: Post the relevant Hibernate mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the mapping XML:

```
    <joined-subclass
        name="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.pessoa.PessoaFisica"
        extends="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.pessoa.Pessoa"
        table="PESSOA_FISICA"
    >
        <key column="id_pessoa" />
        <property name="cpf" column="CPF" />
        <property name="rg" column="RG" />
        <property name="dataNascimento" type="date" column="DATA_NASCIMENTO" />

    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass
        name="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.pessoa.PessoaJuridica"
        extends="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.pessoa.Pessoa"
        table="PESSOA_JURIDICA"
    >
        <key column="id_pessoa" />
        <property name="razaoSocial" column="RAZAO_SOCIAL" />
        <property name="cnpj" column="CNPJ" />
        <property name="inscricaoEstadual" column="INSC_EST" />
        <joined-subclass
            name="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.pessoa.juridica.Cliente"
            extends="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.pessoa.PessoaJuridica"
            table="CLIENTE"
        > 
            <key column="id_pessoa" />
            <property name="telefone" column="TELEFONE" />
        </joined-subclass>    
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
<class name="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.endereco.Endereco"
       table="ENDERECO" >
    <id name="_id" column="_ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="endereco" column="ENDERECO" />
    <property name="numero" column="NUMERO" />
    <property name="complemento" column="COMPLEMENTO" />
    <property name="bairro" column="bairro" />
    <property name="cidade" column="cidade" />
    <property name="uf" column="uf" />
    <property name="cep" column="cep" />
    <property name="tipo" column="tipo" type="character" />
    <property name="status" column="status" type="character" />

    <set name="pessoas" table="PESSOA" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key column="_ID" not-null="true" />
        <one-to-many class="br.com.koinonia.igrejahabil.model.entities.pessoa.Pessoa"/>
    </set>
</class>
```